# How to separate high voltage and low voltage side of a circuit?

Tags: power-supply, switching

I want to design an ATS for a single phase. Here, I have added two sources and also control circuits. But I need to separate the high voltage and low voltage side of the circuit. In order to do that, what should I add in the circuit?
[image]

Comment: What is an ATS?

Comment: First, you should untangle your schematic, so that it is clear what is high voltage and what is low voltage.  D3 and D4 inthe upper left don't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: You have seven voltage sources in your schematic. I'd expect two: one AC and one DC.

Comment: Here, 2 voltage sources are used to provide signals to photo triacs and  2 voltage sources are used to give 5V to the gate of the Triacs. And other sources are uses to provide AC and DC. V7 is used to provide signal to the main control circuit. Is it wrong to use too many voltage sources here? @Transistor

Comment: ATS- Automatic Transfer Switch @AnalogKid

Comment: I am considering one of the sources as Mains and Another one is solar. Should I untangle my schematic to get better information about high and low voltage @PeterBennett

Comment: [Edit] the ATS explanation into your question rather than buried in the comments. Reading the schematic is very hard work. (1) There is no power supply for the Q1, Q2 section as far as I can see. (2) You have component designators lying on top of traces. (3) Use GND symbols to eliminate ground networks. This alone can remove a lot of clutter. (4) Orient your opto-isolators so that current flows from top to bottom. (5) Why are you using opto-isolators at U1 and U4 when you are not using the isolation?

Comment: I think that if you draw U1 and U4 horizontally, with the transistor to the right, most of the high voltage stuff will naturally fall to the right, automatically separating the HV from LV.  Also, you have far too many voltage sources.  You don't show any current-limiting resistors in series with the opto LEDs.

Comment: Label the Mains Supply, Solar Supply, and Load to help us (and you!) understand what is happening in the circuit.